# html/javascript canvas height/width coordinates not the same?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason height and width dont seem to be the same relative to each other here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lo2hgg54/

### javascript

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvass");
var canv=canvas.getContext("2d");
canv.beginPath();
canv.rect(100,100,200,200);
canv.fillStyle="green";
canv.fill();
```

### html

```
<canvas id="canvass">
</canvas>
```

can anyone explain why 200width and 200height arent the same? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your canvas is just not big enough to display the entire rectangle, it's being cut off at the bottom of the canvas, which is why it *looks* like it's not high enough

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvass");
var canv=canvas.getContext("2d");

canv.beginPath();
canv.rect(100,100,200,200);
canv.fillStyle="green";
canv.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvass" height="500" widht="500">
</canvas>
```

The [specification for HTML5 explicitly](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) states that :

> The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults
>   to 150.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the canvas is cut off. If you use the Chrome's debugging tools, you can see that the canvas' dimensions are 300x150px (the default).

Try making your canvas like so:

```
<canvas id="canvass" height="300"></canvas>
```

This will be large enough to contain the rectangle.